# Serial Communication problem - ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've written a serial communication program/driver for controlling a servo.
Now I wanted to use it with ROS.

1. First of all, I setup an empty c++
   ROS package.
2. Second I put the code inside and
   compiled it using ROS facilities. No
   ROS code yet, should basically spit
   out the same functionality, BUT DOES
   NOT!

The issue is that the serial communication doesn't work properly, for instance it can't read the right values at the serial port any more, it does strange things.

If I do compile my prog. using "g++ serial.cpp" and then run the executable everything works fine.

**What does ROS do with my program different from the simple "g++ serial.cpp" command!**

Thank you very much!

Greetings!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77471/serial-communication-problem---ros/) by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-09**:
It should do roughly the same besides maybe linking ROS libraries that shouldn't interfere with your process. Check VERBOSE=1 make to see the exact commands.

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-09**:
Thank you very much for your reply. This is what I get:
pastebin.com/rDxmUxxV

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-09**:
Maybe a start to see what's happening would be to fish out the compile and linker command (c++ .......), try them on your own and see if/what changes. The only ROS things I could image would be: Compile flags your code doesn't like or linked libraries that cause weird behavior.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-09**:
A simple explanation might be that your code is just buggy and the release build (-O2) triggered the bugs. There seem to be a couple of serious warnings.

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-09**:
Thank you very much :)!
I will try it!

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-09-09**:
also, if it's a ros package, shouldn't you use rosmake rather than make? I honestly don't know if that makes any difference, but I thought I'd thow it out there.

**Comment by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) on 2013-09-09**:
Thank you for your replies, it was a very weird error inside the code. It has nothing to do with ROS, though it was very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your replies, it was a very weird error inside the code. It has nothing to do with ROS, though it was very strange.

---

Originally posted by [Ros451](https://answers.ros.org/users/6340/ros451/) with karma: 18 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0